# Optimal String comparison method swift

Tags: swift, string, similarity

What is the best algorithm to use to get a percentage similarity between two strings. I have been using Levenshtein so far, but it's not sufficient. Levenshtein gives me the number of differences, and then I have to try and compute that into a similarity by doing:

```
100 - (no.differences/no.characters_in_scnd_string * 100)
```

For example, if I test how similar `"ab"` is to `"abc"`, I get around 66% similarity, which makes sense, as `"ab"` is 2/3 similar to `"abc"`.

The problem I encounter, is when I test `"abcabc"` to `"abc"`, I get a similarity of 100%, as `"abc"` is entirely present in `"abcabc"`. However, I want the answer to be 50%, because 50% of `"abcabc"` is the same as `"abc"`...

I hope this makes some sense... The second string is constant, and I want to test the similairty of different strings to that string. By similar, I mean `"cat dog"` and `"dog cat"` have an extremely high similarity despite difference in word order.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Using Levenstein algorithm with input:

```
case1 - distance(abcabc, abc)
case2 - distance(cat dog, dog cat)
```

Output is:

```
distance(abcabc, abc) = 3 // what is ok, if you count percent from `abcabc`
distance(cat dog, dog cat) = 6 // should be 0
```

So in the case of `abcabc` and `abc` we are getting 3 and it is 50% of the largest word `abcabc`. exactly what you want to achive.

The second case with `cats` and `dogs`: my suggestion is to split this Strings to words and compare all possible combinations of them and chose the smallest result.

UPDATE:

The second case I will describe with pseudo code, because I'm not very familiar with `Swift`.

```
get(cat dog) and split to array of words ('cat' , 'dog') //array1
get(dog cat) and split to array of words ('dog' , 'cat') //array2

var minValue = 0;

for every i-th element of `array1`
   var temp = maxIntegerValue // here will be storred all results of 'distance(i, j)'
   index = 0 // remember index of smallest temp
   for every j-th element of `array2` 
      if (temp < distance(i, j))
         temp = distance(i, j)
         index = j
   // here we have found the smallest distance(i, j) value of i in 'array2'
   // now we should delete current j from 'array2'  
   delete j from array2

   //add temp to minValue
   minValue = minValue + temp
```

Workflow will be like this:

After first iteration on first `for` statement (for value 'cat' `array1`) we will get 0, because `i = 0` and `j = 1` are identic. Then `j = 1` will be removed from `array2` and after that `array2` will have only elem `dog`.

Second iteration on second `for` statement (for value 'dog' `array1`) we will get also 0, because it is identic with `dog` from `array2`

At least from now you have an idea how to deal with your problem. It is now depends on you how exactly you will implement it, probably you will take another data structure.

Comment: The question is tagged Swift. Answers should be in the appropriate language.

Comment: @rmaddy I have deleted the code. In my answer the main point is not in the exact implementation of Levenshtein algorithm

Comment: Could you please show how you would go about the second case? Thanks for the help

Comment: @HarryStuart I have added an explanation

Answer (score 1):

This implement of algorithms of  `Damerau–Levenshtein distance`  and `Levenshtein distance`

you can check this `StringMetric` Algorithms have what you need

https://github.com/autozimu/StringMetric.swift

Comment: Unfortunately, that algorithm doesn’t work for rearranged words. “cat and dog” and “dog and cat” are supposed to be very similar but have 6 differences